# Transfer data to OPC DA client

Tags: server, client, opc, scada

I have a SCADA system with an OPC DA client module installed on a windows PC.
Additionally I have a measuring instrument connected to the same PC through a COM port.
The instrument measures two numerical values which I can read in Python. I would like to feed the data into the SCADA system, but I don't know how. From what I can read the easiest way would be to apply an OPC DA server and have that communicating with the OPC DA client, but the vendor of the measuring instrument does not provide such a server.

All the information I can find provide details, using different programming languages e.g. Python, C, Visual Studio etc, on how to setup/create an OPC DA client assuming the server is already existing. I however, have the opposite situation where I have the client but not the server part.

Any ideas on how to setup my own OPC DA server so that I can get the measured values from my instrument into the SCADA system are most welcome...or any other ideas on how to fix the data transfer.

Best regards

Comment: Who makes your instrument?  Do they provide any drivers?  Checkout Matrikon or Kepware.  They have a large suite of clients and servers for different protocols.

Comment: What kind of SCADA do you have?  Does it have a database driver or a way to load a file?  Your Python driver could write data to a database or a file for the SCADA to pick up.

Comment: Finally, there are numerous OPC DA SDKs that you could use to develop your own server but that might be an overkill.  Check out https://github.com/SoftingIndustrial/OPC-Classic-SDK